# Use label text in different class using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

First of all, I'm pretty new to Java and therefore to Netbeans. I designed a user interface to gather some information from a TCP/IP connection and it works fine.

After that i created a class to run my "real" project, that needs to use the text from the labels to complete some commands. The UI gathers information like this:

```
client.readVariable(job_name);
String a = job_name.toString();
jLabel1.setText(a);
...
```

So I want to run the class when button1 is clicked ( and i don't know how ) and use the label values. Both of'em are on the same package.

```
job.setJob(jLabel1.getText); //kinda pseudocode
```

How can i manage that ? What's the cleaner way ? I read that i should put both on the same class, but i'm afraid something goes wrong..

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide your full code

Comment: i don't have "full code" for my questions. I simply don't know if it's possible the way i said. The code i have is for each command i send. i.e., `job.setJob()` but i complete it manually. And i'm trying to use the Labels text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't mention your full code i am giving the pseudo code,
Generally you need to create ActionListener object and register this listener object to the Button component then onclick of that button actionPerformed method will be called

```
class MyClass{
private JLabel myLabel;
private JFrame mainFrame;
private JButton myButton;
MyClass(){
      mainFrame = new JFrame();
      mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
      mainFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      myLabel= new JLabel("YourText");
      myButton = new JButton("Click");
      MyListener listener = new MyListener(myLabel.getText());
      myButton.addActionListener(listener);
  }

}
class MyListener implements ActionListener{

 private String jobText;
 private Job job;//Not Sure
 MyListener(String text){
    jobText = text;
    job = new Job();//Not Sure
 }
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    job.setJob(jobText);
 }

}
```

Comment: I understand what your trying to do, but i don't get how this helps me Run the class i want when i click a jButton..

Comment: Since you didn't gave your fill code i gave only pseudo code.By using this try now if you stuck any where then paste your code we'll see how we can help .And what do you mean by "Run the class i want when i click a jButton"?

Comment: sorry for the late answer. Imagine i have a package with a class.java and a gui.java . Can i run the class.java when i click a button on the gui?

Comment: @noidea it's based on the access of that class if it is public you can access any where